# Theorem-environment with Roman numeral for the fifth item?

Tags: theorems, newtheorem

I would like to have Axioms and Definitions and Theorems counted with a Basic Law such as to get for example *Axiom 1, Axiom 2, Definition 3, Theorem 4, Basic Law V, Theorem 6* followed by more items with Arabic numerals. Basic Law V should indeed be the fifth item, and it is the name of a famous assumption in the thinking of the logician Gottlob Frege. How may I define with  \newtheorem in a preamble to obtain the desired effect?

Comment: Are you using `amsthm`?

Comment: @egreg Yes, I do. \documentclass{scrarticle}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage[all]{xy}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{endnotes}
\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage[style =authoryear]{biblatex}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{yfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{csquotes}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the theorem-like environments share the numbering, you just need to make the counter to appear in Roman numerals when it has the value 5.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem} % base
\newtheorem{basic}[theorem]{Basic Law}
\newtheorem{axiom}[theorem]{Axiom}
\newtheorem{definition}[theorem]{Definition}

\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{%
  \ifnum\value{theorem}=5
    \Roman{theorem}%
  \else
    \arabic{theorem}%
  \fi
}

\begin{document}

\begin{axiom}
This is an axiom.
\end{axiom}

\begin{axiom}
This is an axiom.
\end{axiom}

\begin{definition}
This is a definition.
\end{definition}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\begin{basic}
This is the basic law.
\end{basic}

\begin{theorem}
This is a theorem.
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course it's up to you ensuring that it actually is at the fifth place.

Comment: Many thanks! :)